# Chrome isn't loading static content due to HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_INVALID_HEADER - Invalid character in header name - last-modified

Tags: http-headers, google-chrome, dates, date-format, last-modified

```
    HTTP2_SESSION_RECV_INVALID_HEADER
--> error = "Invalid character in header name."
--> header_name = "last-modified:"
--> header_value = "Thursday,%2009-Aug-2018%2001:21:53%20GMT"
```

This error message is preventing static content from being displayed in Chrome

Answer (score 2):

The issue turned out to be the colon in header_name = "last-modified:"  Basically, there were two colons in the ngnix config file, which lead Chrome to throw an error (Firefox, on the other hand,  ignores this and renders the page).  The header_name should simply be header_name = "last-modified"

Answer (score 1):

Despite that that the error description indicates the problem is in the "header name," I suspect that the issue is actually with the header_value.

On StackOverflow, [The date/time format used in HTTP headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120882/the-date-time-format-used-in-http-headers) says

> In [section 14.29 Last-Modified](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.29) you can see that date format should be:
>
> ```
> "Last-Modified" ":" HTTP-date
> ```
>
> An example of its use is
>
> ```
> Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:45:26 GMT
> ```

The last modified date in your error doesn't look like that.   It doesn't have any spaces.  Instead they have been replaced by `%20` which indicates that the date has been [URL encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

I don't know of any reason that the standard HTTP headers should be encoded like that.   See on StackOverflow: [Is it appropriate or necessary to use percent-encoding with HTTP Headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215227/is-it-appropriate-or-necessary-to-use-percent-encoding-with-http-headers)  I'm not sure how you would have configured your server to percent-encode the last-modified header.   However you did it, the solution to your problem should be to remove that encoding.

Chrome is probably encountering the first `%` and is saying "I didn't expect a percent there!  Invalid character."